# Testes com PHPUnit em classe que usa variável $_SERVER

Tags: php, phpunit

Olá, tudo bem com vocês?

Eu criei a seguinte classe pra um mini-framework próprio (desenvolvido para fins de estudo).

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Atlas\Core;

final class Request
{
    private $uri;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }

    public function path(): string
    {
        return $this->uri;
    }
}
```

Como eu posso testar o método `path` dessa classe com PHPUnit? Eu tentei algo assim

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Atlas\Tests\Core;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Atlas\Core\Request;

final class RequestTest extends TestCase
{
    private $request;

    public function assertPreConditions(): void
    {
        $this->request = new Request();
    }

    public function testCheckIfPathMethodReturnString(): void
    {
        $this->assertIsString($this->request->path());
    }
}
```

Mas não funcionou. Essa classe `Request` funciona perfeitamente quando acesso pelo navegador. Porém, quando tento testar ela com PHPUnit, esse método retorna `null`. Aparentemente os valores de $_SERVER mudam já que o que o PHPUnit faz não se trata de uma requisição web convencional.

Ideias?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Ideias? Sim. Remova a dependência da sua classe com as variáveis globais e conseguirá testar mais facilmente. Por que não receber a URL como parâmetro no construtor? Assim, durante os testes, poderá definir exatamente a URL a ser testada. Na aplicação em produção bastará você passar o valor de `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` como parâmetro para funcionar como o esperado.

Comment: @Woss Cara, e não é que faz sentido? Vou esperar pra ver se tem mais respostas igualmente úteis pra acrescentar algo a questão. Enquanto isso, por que você não posta uma resposta com isso que me disse? Daí, é provável que eu marque ela como solução. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é um sinal claro que a construção da sua classe está equivocada. Se é difícil de testar, então a sua classe possui uma dependência construída de forma errada. Neste caso em específico, a dependência que está atrapalhando é a variável global `$_SERVER`. Como você mesmo percebeu, isso será um problema nos testes unitários justamente porque normalmente essa variável é populada automaticamente ao receber a requisição HTTP.

Você consegue contornar essa limitação facilmente através da injeção de dependência, sendo que ao invés de a classe `Request` acessar a URL a parte da variável global ela passe a receber esse valor por parâmetro.

```
classe Request
{
    private string $url;

    public function __construct(string $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }
}
```

Na aplicação você cria a instância com `new Request($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`, enquanto durante os testes unitários pode instanciar com `new Request('url/de/teste')`.

É bastante comum, também, ver nas implementações que os frameworks fazem uma classe filha de `Request` que define a requisição a partir de variáveis de ambiente, como por exemplo:

```
classe ServerRequest extends Request
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    }
}
```

Assim, você pode aplicar todos os testes unitários com base em `Request` e na aplicação utilizar `ServerRequest`, que estará coberta pelos testes justamente devido à herança.

Pensando uma organização DDD, pode considerar a URL como um *Value Object*, então ainda poderia declarar a classe `Url` e colocá-la como dependência da sua classe:

```
classe Request
{
    private Url $url;

    public function __construct(Url $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }
}
```